# Изменение цвета фонового изображения SVG (карусель Bootstrap )

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, svg, background

У меня есть карусель BS 4 с `next/prev` элементами управления, которые пока работают. У меня светлый фон, поэтому я хотел бы изменить цвет элементов управления (в настоящее время `next/prev` белого цвета).

```
<div id="carouselQuotes" class="carousel slide quotecaru" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselQuotes" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselQuotes" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselQuotes" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    ... carousel items ...
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselQuotes" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselQuotes" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Изменить цвет индикаторов было несложно, поскольку для этого просто использовался цвет в качестве фона. Но установка `background-color` или цвета для элементов управления `prev / next` не изменила цвет фактического значка элемента управления.

Я обнаружил, что иконки устанавливаются через SVG фонового изображения. В нем указан цвет заливки:

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

Я пробовал:

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon, .carousel-control-next-icon {
    fill: #000;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon, .carousel-control-next-icon {
    fill: '#000';
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon, .carousel-control-next-icon {
    fill: '%23000';
}
```

Есть ли способ изменить цвет значка, не отменяя всю строку фонового изображения?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Change color of SVG background-image (Bootstrap 4 carousel)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47122852/7394871) от участника  [@bertcc423](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2326791/bertcc423).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/47122852/7394871

Comment: Можно вопрос, а зачем делать переводы вопросов и ответов. Как ответ на распростроненную проблему или что?

Comment: @AndreyFreiz Это программа ассоциаций с Enso На мете много топиков посвященных этой теме Вот почитайте один из [них](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/28748)  Я делаю переводы топиков, которые прежде  всего интересны  мне и надеюсь будут полезны другим.

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете стилизовать содержимое этого фонового изображения SVG с помощью правил CSS.
Он анализируется,  обрабатывается и эффективно превращается в растровое изображение при декодировании.

Вам нужно будет изменить сам SVG. Изменить

`fill="%23fff"`

на

`fill="%23000"`

или в любой желаемый цвет. `%23` здесь просто символ `#`. Он должен быть закодирован в [URL-адресе](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) при использовании в таком URI данных

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
}

button {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}


div.inverted {
  background-color: white;
}

.inverted .carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23000' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></button>
</div>

<div class="inverted">
  <button class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></button>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47133726/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>